# Grails afterInsert hook issue with Hibernate 5.1 and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, grails

In an existing Grails 3.1.15 application, recently upgraded to Hibernate 5.1, an odd issue with afterInsert (or other) hooks started to appear. After some hours of testing, I could track this down to Hibernate 5.1 + PostgreSQL combination - issue is not reproducible with H2. To reproduce, create a simple application consisting of 2 domain objects - an Audit trail and a User, as shown here:

```
class Audit {
    Date dateCreated
    String auditData
}

class User {
    String name
    String email

    def afterInsert() {
        new Audit(auditData: "User created: $this").save()
    }
}
```

The code above works OK with Hibernate 4, however, if the application is upgraded to Hibernate5 plugin + Hibernate 5.1.x (tested with 5.1.0.Final and 5.1.5.Final) the above scenario will always lead to a ConcurrentModificationException when you attempt to save a new `User` instance. You can just use a scaffold controller to reproduce. Note this only happens with PostgreSQL as the data source - with H2 it would still work OK.

Now, according to [GORM Docs](http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/index.html#eventsAutoTimestamping) (see chapter 8.1.3) one should use a new session when attempting to save other objects in beforeUpdate or afterInsert hooks anyway:

```
def afterInsert() {
    Audit.withNewSession() {
        new Audit(auditData: "User created: $this").save()
        /* no exception logged, but Audit instance not preserved */
    }
}
```

But this wouldn't really resolve the issue with PSQL. The exception is gone, the `User` instance is persisted, but the `Audit` instance is not saved. Again, this code would work OK with H2. To really avoid the issue with PSQL, you would have to manually flush the session in afterInsert:

```
def afterInsert() {
    Audit.withNewSession() { session ->
        new Audit(auditData: "User created: $this").save()
        session.flush() 
        /* finally no exceptions, both User and Audit saved */
    }
}
```

**Question:** is this a bug, or is this expected? I find it a bit suspicious that the manual flush is required in order for the `Audit` instance to be persisted - and even more so when I see it works without a flush with H2 and only seems to affect PostgreSQL. But I couldn't really find any reports - any pointers are appreciated!

For the sake of completeness, I tested with the following JDBC driver versions for PostgreSQL:

```
runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1208.jre7'
runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.0.0'
```

And for the upgrade to Hibernate 5.1, the following dependencies were used:

```
classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:5.0.13"
...
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:5.0.13"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.5.Final"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.5.Final"
```

Comment: Seems like expected behavior to me since you don't have a transaction in the new session

Comment: @JamesKleeh my knowledge of the internals is limited but I was expecting it to auto-flush somehow (as I never had to flush it manually before). But most importantly it works without the flush with H2, and now I also tested against MySQL, no issues there either. That's why it seems a bit confusing to me.